# Prove the following determinant without expanding

Tags: determinant

We have to prove the following result without expanding

$\left|\begin{array}{lll}
      a^3 & a^2 &1 \\
b^3 & b^2 &1\\ c^3 & c^2 &1
       \end{array}
\right|=(ab+bc+ca)\left|\begin{array}{lll}
      a^2 & a &1 \\
b^2 & b &1\\ c^2 & c &1
       \end{array}
\right|$

Progress :

$\left|\begin{array}{lll}
      a^3 & a^2 &1 \\
b^3 & b^2 &1\\ c^3 & c^2 &1
       \end{array}
\right|=\frac{1}{abc}\left|\begin{array}{lll}
      a^3 & a^2 &abc \\
b^3 & b^2 &abc\\ c^3 & c^2 &abc
       \end{array}
\right|=\left|\begin{array}{lll}
      a^2 & a &ab \\
b^2 & b & ca\\ c^2 & c &ab
       \end{array}
\right|=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
      a^2+b^2+c^2 & a+b+c &ab+bc+ca\\
b^3 & b^2 &1\\ c^3 & c^2 &1
       \end{array}
\right|$

What will be the next

Comment: Related question: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986008/how-to-prove-the-determinant).